# ASP.NET MVC not loading FontAwesome correctly (blurry)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, less, font-awesome

I might have missed something here, but I feel like I've done every thing possible according FontAwesome's instructions, but I simply cannot get that beautiful smooth font working. My font is less smooth and I don't even think it's set to FontAwesome.

Here's a picture showing my problem in Firefox. It's the same in IE9.
[image: FontAwesome problem]

I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 and Bootstrap (less) and FontAwesome (less) with BundleTransformer.
Here's my BundleConfig class:

```
public class BundleConfig
{
    public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        var cssTransformer = new CssTransformer();
        var jsTransformer = new JsTransformer();
        var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

        var modernizrBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/modernizr")
            .Include("~/Scripts/modernizr-*");
        modernizrBundle.Transforms.Add(jsTransformer);
        modernizrBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;

        var jsBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.min.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js");
        jsBundle.Transforms.Add(jsTransformer);
        jsBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;

        var cssBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/css")
            .Include("~/Content/less/bootstrap.less")
            .Include("~/Content/less/responsive.less");
        cssBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
        cssBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;

        bundles.Add(modernizrBundle);
        bundles.Add(jsBundle);
        bundles.Add(cssBundle);

        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
    }
}
```

I have edited the bootstrap.less file to include `@import "font-awesome.less";` instead of `@import "sprites.less";`, and I have corrected the path to the FontAwesome font directory in font-awesome.less (`@FontAwesomePath: "../font";`).

The generated source code of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <link href="/bundles/css?v=PzV9CBTBs7_DCIpcfH8cCcOoepY8EiM_IKgyY6a02Mw1" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="/bundles/modernizr?v=N72c_KKpFDVtSEIZ3CtjgoN7eDH9Wa28lL9Ncn1mtUw1"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-success" href="#"><i class="icon-shopping-cart icon-large"></i> Checkout</a>
        </p>

        <script src="/bundles/js?v=7PBTQq6BUbxyT95hBnk4xN3Qb852Tl2pCmQoTS6PuLs1"></script>        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have verified that the font path in the generated css points to the correct FontAwesome font files and they are there. Firefox confirms this when loading the page:

```
[12:24:45.372] GET http://localhost:57700/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 1040ms]
[12:24:46.457] GET http://localhost:57700/bundles/css?v=PzV9CBTBs7_DCIpcfH8cCcOoepY8EiM_IKgyY6a02Mw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 7ms]
[12:24:46.458] GET http://localhost:57700/bundles/modernizr?v=N72c_KKpFDVtSEIZ3CtjgoN7eDH9Wa28lL9Ncn1mtUw1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 5ms]
[12:24:46.459] GET http://localhost:57700/bundles/js?v=7PBTQq6BUbxyT95hBnk4xN3Qb852Tl2pCmQoTS6PuLs1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 12ms]
[12:24:47.695] GET http://localhost:57700/Content/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=3.0.1 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
```

I tried setting the font-family of the link to FontAwesome, but then the font is totally off.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fontawesome is just for the icons and not for the text. So in your example, only the cart is being generated by the FontAwesome font which looks fine to me.

The 'Checkout' text is generated by from the body, btn and btn-success classes. On their site FontAwesome has customized these from the base Bootstrap classes by modifying the bootstrap classes.

I'd recommend leaving the base bootstrap css file intact and  creating your own css stylesheet and referencing it below the core bootstrap.css stylesheet which should override the bootstrap styles. I think you only need the body,  btn and btn-success classes, so all you should need to add in the custom style sheet is :

**UPDATE :**

Note that the proxima-nova font is served via  the Typekit webfonts service (https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova).

```
  body {
    font-family: proxima-nova,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    color: #333;
    }
        .btn-success {
        color: #fff;
        text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        background-color: #5bb75b;
        background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#62c462,#51a351);
        background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#62c462),to(#51a351));
        background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#62c462,#51a351);
        background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#62c462,#51a351);
        background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#62c462,#51a351);
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff62c462',endColorstr='#ff51a351',GradientType=0);
        border-color: #51a351 #51a351 #387038;
        border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
        filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
        }
    .btn {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 4px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #333;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.75);
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#fff),to(#e6e6e6));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#fff,#e6e6e6);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff',endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6',GradientType=0);
    border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
    border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
    border-bottom-color: #a2a2a2;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2),0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Judo. I thought it was the actual font aswell. But I still cannot get it working. Lets take a simple paragraph as an example, where we can modify the font directly in the body. Heres a JSFiddle with the body part of your CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/D5xkP/. Here's a picture showing the same paragraph but on FontAwesome's website: http://i.imgur.com/dMcPUGn.png

Comment: Think I found the problem. The default proxima-nova font is a Typekit webfont, this requires a Typekit subscription (https://typekit.com/fonts/proxima-nova) and so just copying the code wont work if it is on a different domain.

Comment: I took a quick look this evening - definitely looks like the font is the issue. If you fire up the chrome dev tools (f12) and edit the style to delete the font, it goes back to the regular font.

Comment: Thanks for taking your time Judo. Not the solution I had hoped for, but it makes sense :-)